# How to replace the flutter's default DNS function to HTTPDNS(DNS over HTTP) in flutter？

Tags: flutter, dart, dns, hook

I am developing a project using flutter.I need replace the  flutter's default DNS function to HTTPDNS (DNS over HTTP) .

When I want to visit a website eg:https://www.google.com/ ,I can  get the website's i IP address from other server like Google Public DNS,then use the IP address visit the website directly.
But if the website has more than one https certificates，I Cann't send the host name in SSL client hello message, so I can't get the right certificates from the server, lead to SSL handshake fail.
I have read the dart SDK api docs and other dart packages ,don't find the api for replace dns function。

Comment: There's a package called "dns" that supports DNS over HTTP. https://pub.dev/packages/dns

Comment: It just provide a function to transform host name to IP addresss,can't replace the flutter's default DNS.

Comment: Any updates now? Thanks

Comment: Any updates now? Thanks